# In Ada95 how many bytes does integer occupied in memory?

Tags: memory-allocation

Also asking for float, character, ect.

Comment: Programming questions are [off-topic, here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If the answer really can't be found by searching the web, [so] is probably the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ada does not have primitives in the same way as most languages. Instead when you define an Integer or Floating Point Type you provide a range.

The compiler then ensures the Type has that range in whatever underlying type it chooses on that system.

The Standard library does however provide some predefined types...

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System

http://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-03-05-02.html